# How do you get window management (window titles etc) working properly for java applications?

Tags: unity, java, window-management

I use several Java applications in my Ubuntu workstation, but they are grouped as one application in the window manager and don't have their application titles. It's frustrating not to be able to Alt Tab through them individually as other applications.

They also all share one question mark as an icon when tabbing though the windows.

Comment: It does sometimes use the icon of the first java application started, but after that the rest mostly fall into the same group

Comment: Try using the Sun JRE if you are using OpenJDK and vice versa.

Comment: thanks, will try that. I've found that in Unity, if I run a compiz --replace then I at least get icons on those applications that have one set. I also get the same problem with a mono aplication that I use, and the compiz replace works for that too.

Comment: *once you are on the application that you want, use the down arrow (while holding alt) to see the windows within the group, and select the desired one.*

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!